# Creating a recursive formula for a piece of code

Tags: java, recursion, formula, master-theorem

I'm doing some homework and I'm struggling with a specific question. There is a similar question in my assignment so I need to get the hang of this.

Here's the code:

```
    public static double power2(double base, int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 1:
            return base;
        case 2:
            return base * base;
        default:
            if (n % 2 == 0) /* n is even */ {
                return power2(power2(base, n / 2), 2);
            } else /* n is odd */ {
                return power2(power2(base, n / 2), 2) * base;
            }
    }
}
```

I have the base case, which I believe to be *0, n=1;*
However, getting to *T(n)* is where I'm struggling.

It needs to be similar *T(n-1)+c, n>1.*

I need to express the code with a recursive formula.

Can anyone ELI5 this for me?

Comment: What do you want to do? "Find out how many time a number can be divided by 2"?

Comment: [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)?

Comment: @ozgur I need to express the code with a recursive formula, T(n).

Comment: @Vlad Yes, that's correct. It isn't referred to as such in my textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm tempted to say the recurrence is

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)
```

If you rewrite the general case as

```
double temp = power2(base, n/2); // T(n/2)
if (n%2 == 0) {
  return power2(temp, 2); // O(1) by looking at the base case
} else {
  return power2(temp, 2) * base; // O(1) by looking at the base case
}
```

which makes it

```
O(log(n))
```

This [document](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~dmarino/ucf/cop3502/lec_biswas/recursion12.pdf) covers the specific problem you're looking at. They're probably doing a better job than I am, I haven't looked at the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) in a long time.

Comment: So if it is stipulated that it takes *c* units of time to do a multiplication, the recurrence would be 'T(n) = T(n/2) + c' ? Would multiplying by the base an extra time when the number is odd make it *2c*? Regardless, thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. I suppose in the n-is-odd case, it would be 2c, one c for the n=2 base case, and then another c for the `*base` at the end.

Comment: Right. That makes sense. Thanks a bunch.